# I can't login to Ubuntu on Virtualbox

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, login-screen

When I enter my password and press enter, it processes for a while and then loops me right back to the account login screen again. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I've tried using the advice on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) but nothing worked.  After trying the steps outlined on [this response](https://askubuntu.com/a/223503/359769) on the thread, I ended up with the lubuntu login screen and don't know how to get out of it.

I appreciate any help. Thx.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Comment: i looks like an X11 issue.
inside the VM open virtual terminal 2 (hit alt + ctrl + f2)
login, and sudo apt install virtual-box-guest-x11

Answer (score 8):

Installing guest additions solved the same issue for me. You have to do it through terminal.

1. In the "Devices" menu click "Insert Guest Additions CD image" .
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open a virtual terminal. Then login with username and password.
3. Mount the guest additions cd and install the thing:

   ```
   mkdir /tmp/cd
   sudo mount /dev/sr0 /tmp/cd
   sudo /tmp/cd/VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```
4. After it is done, restart the virtual machine and it should work:

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

Comment: I've done that and VirtualBox has updated guest additions to the newest version, but I'm still stuck at the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, what worked was enabling Virtualization on my host computer's BIOS.

After that it all worked.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a PATH problem.

I've changed PATH value in  `/etc/environment` and mistakenly I've overridden the default value.
thus the solution was to log into the system in Cli mode (right cltrl+f1 or f3) then restore the original PATH value

Comment: echo $PATH
it should be /bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin/:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin